# The support of $f(x)= \cos(x)$

Tags: harmonic-analysis

The support of a function is the closure of the set of points where the function has non zero values.

The function $f(x)=\cos(x)$ is zero only at the points $x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

So the support of $f$ is the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \notin \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

From this, how can we deduce that the support of $f$ then equal to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Do you know that, for example, the closure of $(0,1)\cup(1,2)=[0,2]$?

Comment: No I did not, what property is that? So anything with periodic non zero values has closure $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No but if you remove countably many points from $\Bbb R$ then the closure will get you all of $\Bbb R$ back.

Comment: $x$ is in the closure of a set $A$ if there are points in $A$ that are arbitrarily close to $x$.  So you can see that $(0,1)$ has points arbitrarily close to $1$ (and $0$ for that matter).  So the closure of $(0,1)$ is $[0,1]$.

Comment: @gregorygrant I understand

Answer (score 0):

> So the support of $f$ is the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \notin \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

No. It is the *closure* of the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \notin \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

> From this, how can we deduce that the support of $f$ then equal to $\mathbb{R}$?

By showing that the closure of $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \notin \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.